# Prevent Links browser from share cookies when opened by multiple screen

Tags: links

By default, if open multiple `screen` browsing same website, it use same cookies.

I don't want Links browser to write anything on disk while browsing, so that I can open multiple `screen` without same cookies.

I've tried installing in chroot jail. It giving below error:

```
Unable to find or create links2 config directory. Please check, that you have $HOME variable set correctly and that you have write permission to your home directory.
```

Actually, above is what I need in the host machine. But where is `links2` config directory? I need to disable the write permission.

I have tried searching but could not find it.

Or is there better workaround?

-----------added:

I find out `Links` will create `~/.links2` directory when started. If deleted, it will keep creating this directory. If we set permission, it will override it.

In my chroot jail, there is no `~` due to old version `uck`

Answer (score 0):

**Direct answer**

use

```
links -no-connect <websiteURL>
```

Or

```
links -anonymous <websiteURL>
```

On one or both monitors to prevent the sharing of cookies*

**explanation of claim above**

I believe

```
-anonymous
```

would prevent disk cookies altogether and

```
-no-connect
```

will launch it as if the other didn't exist (if I am understanding "separate instance" correctly in terms of a web browser)

links is my go to browser, ill **experiment**
logging into my email now

quitting

```
links yahoo.com
```

**doesn't** prompt sign in

going tty2:
Confirmed normal Opening **doesn't** require login again.

```
links -anonymous yahoo.com
```

**does** prompt login

again confirming

```
links yahoo.com
```

**does not** without options

```
links -no-connect
```

**does** prompt login

It's not hard proof, but we cannot **conclude** that no malicious cookies are preserved, **however** both

```
 -anonymous
```

and

```
-no-connect
```

options have

```
links
```

launch browsers unaware of **at least some, I'm guessing all** , of the users cookies not generated within them.

As shown using the login cookies of yahoo mail

**TL;DR**

there are options (see

```
man links
```

)

```
-anonymous
```

And

```
-no-connect
```

Which do prevent sharing of cookies.*

*I cannot say they prevent **any** sharing of cookies, but as shown above they do prevent sharing of *at least some* cookies,

I am avoiding an unearned conclusion (the difference between "for all" and "for some" can be tough for some, if anyone can improve on my answer **please do**. But I did answer the question (how to prevent separate windows of links from sharing cookies) if it was meant to be "how to prevent separate windows of links from sharing **any** cookies, my quick expiriment and understanding of the man page is insufficient. I would love for someone to guarantee the options act as it would seem **for all cookies**, **for any site**. I assume they do, but this is all I have to offer

Maybe I need to add,

use

```
links -no-connect <websiteURL>
```

Or

```
links -anonymous <websiteURL>
```

On one or both monitors to prevent the sharing of cookies*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does a robot know if I answered the question? Anyways, are the edits clear enough. They do technically answer the question.